# Is $P(X|y)$ continuous in $y$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables with joint CDF $F_{XY}(x,y)=P(X\leq x, Y\leq y)$. Suppose the marginals $F_X(x)$ and $F_Y(Y)$ are continuous. When can we say $F_{X|Y}(x|y)$ is continuous in $y$?

Comment: What you conclude after applying the algebra of continuous functions on the quotient $F_{X/Y}(x/y) = P(X=x,Y=y) / P(Y=y)$? whenever $P(Y=y) \neq 0$

Comment: So first off, just to clarify, $F_{X|Y}(x|y)=P(X\leq x, Y=y)/P(Y=y)$. Also, don't we then need the joint to be continuous because from what is given in the question $F_{XY}(x,y)$ is not necessarily continuous ?